# Environment Variables in Python PYCHARM

Tags: pycharm, environment

Understanding what the [Paths to ".env" files:] does in Edit Configuration PYCHARM

I have been searching for an easy way to create a text file with all my environment variables I use frequently. I know if I go RUN>EDIT CONFIGURATION>ENVIRONMENT VARS I can add them for that config. However I have found that I can also change the [Paths to ".env" files:] to a text file containing my environvars and it seems to work well. I am just curious if this is bad practice and I should go back to manually creating them in the edit configuration's environment variables section. Any Advice?